# Wand can not set image resolution right

Tags: python, wand

I'm trying to create a new jpeg image with resolution 300dpi.

```
with Image(width=300, height=300, background=Color('white'), units = 'pixelsperinch', 
resolution=(300,300)) as ImgBackground:
    ImgBackground.save(filename='ImgOut.jpg')
```

But the resolution of this file is still 72dpi/inch in photoshop.

I don't know why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```py
with Image(width=300, height=300, background='white') as img:
    img.resolution = 300
    img.units = 'pixelsperinch'
    img.save(filename='output.jpg')
```

This is an odd behavior for Wand as the arguments in the constructor are intended for the image *decoder*. If you would like to influence the image *encoder*; then set the property on the image object's *instance*.